# Turning Instagram's "created_time" key into an actual date

Tags: php, api, instagram

I'm using Instagram's API to fetch a given profile's most recent video or photo that was posted. It's working well, except that I can't seem to make sense of what the "created_time" value means.

```
$feed = file_get_contents("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/".$id."/media/recent/?access_token=".$access_token."&count=1");
$feed = @json_decode($feed, true);
$created_on = $feed['data'][0]['created_time'];
```

The `$created_on` variable in this case is set to `1382576494`. When I try to do,

```
echo date('M j, Y', strtotime($created_on));
```

I get an error message. What sort of format is Instagram using?

Comment: This looks like a unix timestamp - seconds since 1 Jan 1930

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instagram is using unix timestamp, so in your case:

```
echo date('M j, Y', $created_on);
```

Comment: date('M j,Y', 1382576494) will give you Oct 24,2013 (depending on your timezone of course). If $created_on is a timestamp then the answer is valid.

Comment: For JavaScript developers reaching this answer, the `Date` object should be newed with a timestamp in milliseconds. Thus: `new Date(photo.created_on * 1000)`

Comment: As in the comment from @aymericbeaumet: Same goes for C# devs: `new DateTime(photo.created_on * 1000)`

Comment: This still holds true with the new api, but remember to swap created_on with created_time. I.e for js use: `new Date(photo.created_time * 1000)`